# How do I extend a class/mixin which has dynamically formed selector

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

How do I extend a Less class which is dynamically formed using & combinator?

Less which generates expected output:

```
.hello-world {
  color: red;
}

.foo {
  &:extend(.hello-world);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Expected CSS output:

```
.hello-world,
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.foo {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Less does not generate expected output:

```
.hello {
  &-world {
    color: red;
  }
}

.foo {
  &:extend(.hello-world);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Unexpected CSS output:

```
.hello-world {
  color: red;
}
.foo {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I think this is not possible currently. You may want to check [this thread](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1539#issuecomment-24256428) and the workaround provided there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Extending a **dynamically formed selector** (loosely using the term) like that is currently not possible in Less. There is an open [feature request](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2200) to support this. Till it is implemented, here are two work-around solutions to it.

**Option 1:**

Write the contents of `.hello` and `.hello-world` selectors into a separate Less file (say `test.less`), compile it to get the CSS. Create another file for the rules of `.foo`, import the compiled CSS as a Less file (using the `(less)` directive) and then extend the `.hello-world` as you had originally intended to.

**test.less:**

```
.hello {
  &-world {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

**extended-rule.less:**

```
@import (less) "test.css";
.foo {
  &:extend(.hello-world);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
.hello-world,
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.foo {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

This method would work because by the time the `test.css` file is imported, the selector is already formed and is no longer dynamic. The drawback is that it needs one extra file and creates dependency.

---

**Option 2:**

Write a dummy selector with rules for all properties that need to be applied to both `.hello-world` and `.foo` and extend it like:

```
.dummy{
    color: red;
}
.hello {
  &-world:extend(.dummy) {};
}

.foo:extend(.dummy){
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

This creates one extra selector (dummy) but is not a big difference.

**Note:** Adding my comment as an answer so as to not leave the question unanswered and also because the work-around specified in the thread linked in comments doesn't work for me as-is.