# Mixin treat 2 equal class definitions differently

Tags: less, less-mixins

I start with a simple example:

```
.classA {
  color: red;
  .otherClass {
       color: yellow;
  }
}
.classB {
  .classA;
}
```

results in:

```
.classA {
  color: red;
}
.classA .otherClass {
  color: yellow;
}
.classB {
  color: red;
}
.classB .otherClass {
  color: yellow;
}
```

But:

```
.classA {
  color: red;
}
.class A .otherClass {
  color: yellow;
}
.classB {
  .classA;
}
```

results in:

```
.classA {
  color: red;
}
.class A .otherClass {
  color: yellow;
}
.classB {
  color: red;
}
```

I can't figure out why the compiler does not include the `.otherClass` in `.classB`. I mean both `classA` definitions are equal aren't they?

Is there a simple explanation for the weird behavior?
Especially, is there a way to include `.otherClass` via mixins or do I have to copy the code?

Comment: I'm not a less expert, but what I see here is exactly what I would have expected. In case one, `.classB` references the `.classA` selector which IN it has the `.otherClass`, so it will be expanded for classB to. And in case two it references the class `.classA` selector which does not have the . otherClass IN IT (`.classA .otherClass` is a different selector), so it is not expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean both classA definitions are equal aren't they?

Nope, they indeed create equal CSS selectors/rulesets, but their *Less definition* is what exactly is different (in fact it's one Less ruleset definition in the first snippet, and two independent ruleset definitions in the second).

In other words:
Mixins facility does not work with *selectors* in a HTML-like fashion (yep, this may be surprising at first). Mixins work with *rulesets* and their [scope](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-scope), thus the mixin expansion rule is as simple as:

> `.foo` will match `.foo` ruleset(s) *only* (and expand all code defined inside that `.foo` only)

thus any separately defined `.foo .bar` etc. rulesets are never involved with `.foo` calls. (And yes, it never actually matters what CSS selectors either stuff results in the end. The only exception to this is [`namespaces`](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-namespaces-and-accessors), but that's another big story I don't want to confuse you with).

For your particular example I'd say that [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) will fit better.

Comment: And for a code like this, this [remark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852586/interpolated-class-names-and-extend-in-less-for-bem-use#comment51633382_31852586) is usually useful (so you won't get to use such code too much from the earliest steps).