# Extend in Less like it Sass can

Tags: less

I like to use `:extend()` in Less like I can do it in Sass.

Example in SCSS: http://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/qEeQPG

Example in Less: http://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/qEeQpz (not worked)

Expected output:

```css
.datalist-item {
  display: block;
}
.datalist-item-term {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.datalist-item-description {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.datalist-float .datalist-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
.datalist-float .datalist-item:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

The purpose is to not self-repeat, so if I rename one class in Sass I have not to rename others.

I know I can put root class in a variable and use it twice with it http://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/qEeQpz but it looks ugly :(

Comment: It seems like SASS extends just the selector (`datalist-item`) but not the properties within it. I don't think this sort of extend is possible in Less currently.

Comment: Also, Less currently cannot extend selectors formed through concatenation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879871/how-do-i-extend-a-class-mixin-which-has-dynamically-formed-selector/26450099#26450099

Comment: I can't see why `extend` is used in such use-case. There's no repeating properties in any of those classes in the `expected result` at all. [Hence no need for `extend`](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/dbbf6a9ad50a3458c963).

Comment: Also speaking of re-using the same selector-name-particle via variable, you may use the same thing with `item` - [demo](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/733851e3357776f32d33), and this way I wonder if it can be considered more ugly than the code in `qEeQPG`.

Answer (score 5):

Your Sass (SCSS) example uses [@extend-Only Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664086/extend-in-less-like-it-sass-can) which is some special form of extending which does not exists in Less.

Firstly a "normal" extend:

SCSS:

```
.class {
p: 1;
}
.class2 {
@extend .class;
}
```

and Less:

```
.class {
p: 1;
}
.class2 {
&:extend(.class);
}
```

both compile into:

```
.class,
.class2 {
  p: 1;
}
```

In Less `.class2 { &:extend(.class); }` can also be written as `.class2:extend(.class1){}`

Now consider the following SCSS code which uses @extend-Only Selectors:

```
%class {
 p: 1;
}

.class2 {
@extend %class;
}
```

The preceding code compile into CSS code as follows:

```
.class2 {
   p: 1; }
```

Sass documentation tells you:

> @extend-Only Selectors
>
> Sometimes you’ll write styles for a class that you only ever want to
>   @extend, and never want to use directly in your HTML. This is
>   especially true when writing a Sass library, where you may provide
>   styles for users to @extend if they need and ignore if they don’t.
>
> If you use normal classes for this, you end up creating a lot of extra
>   CSS when the stylesheets are generated, and run the risk of colliding
>   with other classes that are being used in the HTML. That’s why Sass
>   supports “placeholder selectors” (for example, %foo).
>
> Placeholder selectors look like class and id selectors, except the #
>   or . is replaced by %. They can be used anywhere a class or id could,
>   and on their own they prevent rulesets from being rendered to CSS.

In Less you will have two options to have code that does not generate output:

1) use a mixin, mixins do not generate output:

```
.class() {
p: 1;
}
.class2 {
.class();
}
```

outputs:

```
.class2 {
   p: 1; 
}
```

2) put your classes which should not output in a different file and import this file with the `reference` kewyword:

file1.less:

```
.class {
p: 1;
}
```

file2.less:

```
@import (reference) "file1";
.class2 {
&:extend(.class);
}
```

`lessc file2.less` will output now:

```
.class2 {
   p: 1; 
}
```

But i agree with @seven-phases-max in the comments in the first place. In your example there is no need to use extend. @seven-phases-max shows you some examples to solve this use case. Alternatively you can consider; changing selector order with parent reference, which should work in both [Less](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order) and SASS:

```
.datalist-item {
  display: block;

  &-term {
  font-weight: normal;
  }

  &-description {
  font-weight: bold;
  }

  .datalist-float & {
  display: inline-block;

      &:not(:last-of-type) {
      margin-right: 1em;
      padding-right: 1em;
      border-right: 1px solid;
      }  

  }

}
```

Compile into:

```
.datalist-item {
  display: block;
}
.datalist-item-term {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.datalist-item-description {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.datalist-float .datalist-item {
  display: inline-block;
}
.datalist-float .datalist-item:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

Finally notice that you are using nesting of properties such as:

```
 border: {
     right: 1px solid;
 };
```

which should compile into:

```
border-right { 
1px solid; 
}
```

Less does NOT support nesting of properties.

Comment: Nice explanation. Any specific reasons why the code formatting is a bit out of order?

Comment: Sorry, but I already know all of this. The main reason why I want to `@extend` placeholders is to not repeat in selector names. DRY.

Comment: In your example you can possible use a double & reference `&-float &`, see: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpPaGK