# Why is less `extend` not working when extended class is nested (.button { &_red{} })?

Tags: less

why `extend` is not working in this case?

```
.button {
  &_red {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

.panel {
  .button:extend(.button_red) {}
}
```

Actual output:

```
.button_red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Expected output:

```
.button_red {
  background-color: red;
}
.panel .button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

OR

```
.button_red,
.panel .button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I extend a class/mixin which has dynamically formed selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879871/how-do-i-extend-a-class-mixin-which-has-dynamically-formed-selector)

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue about this bug: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1597